# Logical issue regarding broadcasting messages to clients

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

im currently developing a game on Node js using sockets.

If you can picture a multiplayer game and having 3 seperate rooms. So i go on the website, room 1 has 16/16 players so i go to room 2. That sort of deal.

Logically, the game information for the game running in room 1 should only be sent to the users in room 1 so something like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.rooms.length; i++){
     for (var j = 0; j < this.rooms[i].players; j++){
         io.sockets.connected[this.rooms[i].players[j].socketid].emit('updateGame', this.rooms[i]);
     }
}
```

I havnt tested it or anything but that would be the general logic behind it.

It looks very server heavy since its a fast moving game where on a bigger scale this would have maybe 500 players each at 60fps.

Alternativly i could just emit the infomation of all games to everyone

```
this.socket.of('game').emit('updateGame', this.rooms);
```

And display the correct one client side.

What would be logically best taking into consideration the server stress, efficiancy, best practise etc. It seems like the second one but the thought of sending every single game/ room to the client when they are only play 1 bugs me abit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About handle join exist room or create new room I think you can use Redis Adapter like this on Server side:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);
const redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redisAdapter({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));

io.on('connection', function(client) {
    //Get allRooms by Redis Adapter
    io.of('/').adapter.allRooms((err, rooms) => {
        let statusJoinedRoom = false
        for (let room of rooms) {
            if (socket.id !== room) {
                let numClients = io.sockets.clients(room).length
                if (numClients <= MAX_CLIENTS_IN_ROOM) {
                    socket.join(room, () => {
                        console.log(`Joined room: ${room}`)
                        statusJoinedRoom = true
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!statusJoinedRoom) {
            socket.join(`room${rooms.length+1}`, (){
                console.log('Created new room')
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Workflow is: `Get all rooms` -> `Check count clients in each Room` -> `Join if count clients < MAX_CLIENTS_IN_ROOM` -> `Create new room if all Rooms full`

About performance Redis cache will help storage rooms, clients data. With normal case these data will save on memories of Node thread.

About `emit` to all clients in same room, you can use this

```
socket.to(socket.rooms).emit('hello', "to all clients in room except sender")
```

Hope this help!